# WCF Contract Attributes

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF so can any one explain what is the use of using the attributes in

Service contract attributes like:

- Namespace
- ConfigurationName
- Name
- CallBackContract
- HasProtectionLevel
- Session Mode
- Protection Level

Operation contract attributes like:

- Action
- ReplyAction
- AsyncOperation
- IsOneWay
- IsTerminating

Data contract attributes:

- IsRequired
- EmitDefaultValue
- Order

Can anyone please help me learn more about these attributes.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

The online MSDN documentation is your first source for things like that:

- Read about the `ServiceContractAttribute` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx)
- Read about the `OperationContractAttribute` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx)
- Read about the `DataContractAttribute` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)

All the MSDN documentation pages contain detailed explanations of all the settings on those contract attributes.